# How to have Relative but not liquid layout

Tags: jquery, css

I am new at CSS and just wondering if it is possible to have a relative layout design which can modify by the browsers screen size BUT NOT to be Liquid.

For example if user minimize the screen page still keeps everything in the same layout as full screen.
I am not sure this is possible but what I have is a relative layout which is working perfectly in full screen format but when user minimize or re size the page all pictures and text also minimize, this is not too bad for some elements like img(s) but it also affect on my Navigation Menu which looks awful when I re size the page.Is there a way I can stop it?

Comment: You're looking for "responsive design". Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be trying is to keep the size of your containers bound to a minimum width so they do not get resized alongside the browser. In order to achieve that you can use the **min-width** CSS property.

```
<!-- Document -->
<div id="site-wrapper"></div>
<!-- Document -->
```

The property should be used as such

```
#site-wrapper { min-width: 1000px; /*For example*/ }
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply but I have a sample like this: (Please take a look at following link) http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/nuC69/9/   as you can see all boxes are related together so do I have to set min-width property for all of them.Do I have to do this for Height as well?

Comment: If your element width is set to 100%, by declaring the min-width of the wrapper the elements should keep to that minimum width. There is also the property min-height but I am not sure from your example if it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

you can use CSS3 Media Queries.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Hi Raminson, thanks for your reply but I am not writing css for diffident browsers in Tablet, Phones or PC's this is just on a big screens

Answer (score 1):

What you talking about is called "Responsive Design".

If you want a good example of this (and also, just a great starting point), check out Bootstrap  at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Take a look at their menu at the top, and watch what happens when you make the Viewport smaller (resize your window).

EDIT:

I think what he is asking, is if he can have it "resize" width wise, but keep elements from squishing height wise. His JSFiddle was using percentage heights.

```
.row_1
{
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20;
}
.row_2
{
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 30px 0px;
}

.row_3 {
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    z-index: 20;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here's an updated JSFiddle that may help?

http://jsfiddle.net/xBaTN/

Comment: Hi Cameron, Thanks for comment but I was looking for some solution on using a relative layout BUT NOT liquid. This solution is perfect for cross browsers but not my answer!

Comment: @Behseini - Can you maybe elaborate more as to what your trying to accomplish? I can only see 3 possible "layouts". A `fixed width` layout (`width: 960px;`), a `fluid width` layout (`width: 80%;`), or a `Responsive` layout, wich is a fluid layout with JavaScript helpers to make sure elements never get too small without changing.

Comment: Actually. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/xBaTN/ - Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Applehat, Thanks for your reply but I think the best solution is what cosmin said:just setting min-width will fix the issue